# R - Running a t-test from piping operators

Tags: r, dplyr, piping

Is it possible to run a `t.test` from `piping` operators?
I tried to find the answer to this, but most of the questions around this topic look at doing many tests on the same dataset.
I've looked a `broom` package, but it seems to be good for reading the results.
What I'm interested in is whether it's possible to just use `piping` and run the `t.test()` on the output.
For example, here is some sample data

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data.frame(
  group = sample(LETTERS[1:2], size = 10, replace = T),
  amount = sample(1:3, size = 10, replace = T)
  )
```

If I run a `t.test` using `base R`, I get the results:

```
t.test(d$amount~d$group, var.equal = T)
> d
   group amount
1      A      2
2      A      2
3      B      1
4      B      3
5      A      2
6      B      1
7      B      2
8      A      1
9      B      3
10     A      3
```

But if I try an use `piping`, I get errors:

```
d %>% t.test(amount~group, var.equal = T)

Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(y) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
2: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Do I need to do some additional manupulations?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can place it inside `summarise` as a `list`

```
d %>%
  summarise(ttest = list(t.test(amount ~ group, var.equal = TRUE)))
```

and if we need to extract only the pvalue, this can be done

```
d %>% 
  summarise(pval = t.test(amount ~ group, var.equal = TRUE)$p.value)
```

---

Or we can place it inside the `{}` and then do the `t.test`

```
d %>%
     {t.test(.$amount ~ .$group, var.equal = TRUE)}
```

Or without the braces by specifying the `data` for the formula method

```
d %>%
     t.test(amount ~ group, data = ., var.equal = TRUE)
```

EDIT: based on @hpesoj626's comments

Comment: @hpesoj626  You are right.  I was checking the `.$amount ~ .`

Comment: great, all I was missing the the `data = .` argument.

Answer (score 1):

The 'rstatix' a package deals exactly with performing basic statistical tests within a pipe

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstatix/rstatix.pdf

rstatix provides wrappers of functions like t.test(), or cohensD(), making it possible to use them with pipe operators. Performing a t-test as you required would simply work using their wrapper of t.test(), t_test():

```
d %>% t_test(amount ~ group, var.equal = T)
```